# LESS mixin for nested and non-nested rules

Tags: css, less

Now I'm using LESS to customize Bootstrap to my own website.
I have a problem with LESS's mixins.

For example, the following LESS code:

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
  .Small {
      color: #111;
  }
}
.Small {
    font-size: 5px;
}

.MyArticle {
  .Article;
  .Address {
    .Small;
  }
}
```

is compiled to the following CSS:

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.Article .Small {
  color: #111;
}
.Small {
  font-size: 5px;
}
.MyArticle {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.MyArticle .Small {
  color: #111;
}
.MyArticle .Address {
  color: #111;
}
```

However, in addition to the above generated CSS, I want to make ".MyArticle .Address"  small:

```
.MyArticle .Address {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

What is the best way?

**EDITED:**

In the above example of LESS code, the .Article and .Small are the library's class, and I don't want to modify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem is Scoping

In your original layout, by including `.Article` at the same level as `.Address` is defined, then it is using the `.Small` from the `.Article` as the only mixin, because it is the "local" `.Small` in the `.Address` context. To avoid this, the `.Article` must be isolated to its own block. But then you lose the color being picked up from it's `.Small`, so it must be explicitly included back into `.Address` through a namespaced call. The code ends up like this:

**LESS**

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
  .Small {
      color: #111;
  }
}
.Small {
    font-size: 5px;
}

.MyArticle {
  .Address {
     .Small;
     .Article > .Small;
  }
  & {.Article;}
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.Article .Small {
  color: #111;
}
.Small {
  font-size: 5px;
}
.MyArticle {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.MyArticle .Address {
  font-size: 5px;
  color: #111;
}
.MyArticle .Small {
  color: #111;
}
```

Comment: This is what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, but possibly this code:

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
  .Small {
      color: #111;
  }
}
.Small {
    font-size: 5px;
}

.MyArticle {
  .Article;
  .Address {
    .Small;
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code does make '.MyArticle .Address' to be small, but, instead, '.Small' which is not in '.Article' is no longer small. I don't want to destroy original styles of .Article and .Small.

Comment: Well, add Small class at the end of the code. EDIT: I improved code, maybe it's better now?

Comment: It's lack of my explanation, but, in my example, the codes about .Article and .Small are the exterior library's code. I don't want to modify them. In fact, since there are many such codes, it's too hard to rewrite all of them.

Comment: In that case it would be more efficient just add font-size: 5px; to .Address after .Small class.

Answer (score 0):

Try `extend`:

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
  .Small {
      color: #111;
  }
}
.Small {
    font-size: 5px;
}

.MyArticle {
  .Article;
  .Address {
    &:extend(.Small);
  }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.Article {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.Article .Small {
  color: #111;
}
.Small,
.MyArticle .Address { //<-- this
  font-size: 5px;
}
.MyArticle {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.MyArticle .Small {
  color: #111;
}
```